# PHP PEAR HTTP PUT

Tags: php, http, http-headers, pear, put

I've got problems with PHP PEAR and HTTP PUT. I want to create a HTTP PUT request and attach a file to it and send it to a REST service. Here's my current code:

```
require_once ('includes/HTTP_Request/Request.php');

$url            = 'http://myurl.com/';
$req =& new HTTP_Request();
$req->setMethod(HTTP_REQUEST_METHOD_PUT);
$req->setURL($url);
$req->addHeader('Content-type', 'multipart/form-data');
$tmp_file = 'temp.rdf';
$result = $req->addFile('metadata', $tmp_file, 'text/xml');
if (PEAR::isError($result))
{
    echo $result->getMessage();
}

$response = $req->sendRequest();

if (PEAR::isError($response)) {
        echo $response->getMessage();
} else {
        echo $req->getResponseBody();
}
```

This code should work correctly, but obviously is doesn't. I always get the respond by the REST repository that the header doesn't contain multipart/form-data.

Does anyone know what I can do to get the code to work? Thanks in anticipation!

Answer (score 0):

Use `setBody( string $body)` instead of addFile.

> Sets the request body (for POST, PUT
>   and similar requests)

Comment: but how can i add a file then? or multiple files?

Comment: i need to set different variables at my request:

Comment: 2. 'data' -> application/zip (optionally)

Comment: I'm not sure if on a PUT request more than one file is possible?!

Comment: if i would use setBody() how can i specify a variable name for the body? My repository needs the variable "metadata" to be set.